# Notification Icon when downloading file

Tags: java, android

Does anyone knows how to use notification icon in status bar when downloading a file? Just like when you are downloading a file in app store. The icon is like in gif.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use the default android resource `android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download` for this.

Comment: Works great but I needed to add `setTicker("")` for the animation to play. Credit goes to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15311161/1276636).

Comment: What can i do if downloading is completed?

Comment: I have done with this `mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done);`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fully functioning example that will show the default "system" download notification icon in the status bar.

```
private static void showProgressNotification(Context context, int notificationId, String title, String message)
{
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
    .setTicker("")
    .setProgress(0, 0, true);

    manager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And when your "download" operation is done, clear the notification:

```
private static void hideProgressNotification(final NotificationManager manager, final Context context, final int id)
{
    manager.cancel(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Android Download Manager. It shows a notification icon indicating that there are files downloading. [Android Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)