# Android: Show Animation in status bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

i want notify user this service is running in status bar with an animation 
**but can't show animation or colors**

i saw these questions but don't sloved my problem:

[How to animate the progress notification icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037962/how-to-animate-the-progress-notification-icon)

[Animation in Notification bar Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688052/animation-in-notification-bar-custom-view)

[Android - show animated status bar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311135/android-show-animated-status-bar-icon)

```
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name_persian));
//    builder.setContentText(getText(R.string.app_is_running));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_animation);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    notificationManager.notify(13, builder.build());
```

my animation drawable:
[image]

what i see:
[image]
[image]

Comment: `and the problem is` <-- continue this

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i complete my question

Comment: still no problem or *question* in your question.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot. where do you want to have a animation. It always good to add screenshots

Comment: do your animation icons differ only with a color? Probably the smallicon does not support colors

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes, if i use setLargeIcon() can i show colors??

Comment: @RohitSingh added

Comment: it shows only a smallicon in the statusbar. So I don't think that you can show the colors in the statusbar. But you probably can show that animation in the notification using the largeicon (the last screenshot in your question). Any way, I suggest you just to try and see if it works.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you, i think if i use show and hide animat in status bar and show colors in notification, my problem sloved

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if u post it in answer i check it thanks

Comment: I'm still not sure that it will work. Could you try and if it does - then I post an answer?